# HTML PayPal Form Input Show On Payment

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

So, I have this basic required text forum input on my paypal button. How do I make it so when the person it buys it, the text they put in shows up on my payment or invoice?

Comment: any code for us to look at? or is this question asking us to write the whole thing for you

Comment: I guess so, this is my button. http://pastebin.com/u5Me7H6C

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'My Saved buttons' in PayPal profile, click 'edit' on this button, in "Edit your PayPal payment button' page,there is a customize button section in which you need to check 'Add text field'.